# Flink not giving full reason as to why job submission failed

Tags: apache-flink

After upgrading Flink to 1.7.2, when I try to submit a job from the dashboard and there's some issue with the job, the job submission fails with the following error.

```
Exception occurred in REST handler: org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: The main method caused an error.
```

There's no other reason given as to why the job failed to submit. This was not the case in 1.4.2. Is there a way to see the full reason why the job failed to deploy? I see the same error in the logs too with no additional information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue in version 1.7.2. It has been fixed in 1.8.0.

Jira ticket - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-11902